# Mapping elements of one list multiple times to elements of a second list

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I have two lists and I want to map them to each other, but one list contains more than 1 elements. So I zip them together, but it is not working properly.

The list looks like this:

```
a = ['TEMP', 'TEMP,PRE', 'TEMP,HUM,RAN', 'HUM']
b = ['TEM', 'BAR', 'BAO', 'RAI']
```

I am trying to achieve this:

```
TEM.TEMP
BAR.TEMP
BAR.PRE
BAO.TEMP
BAO.HUM
BAO.RAN
RAI.HUM
```

I want to map every item of `b` to `a`, but in `a` there are more values separated by `,`

My code is as follows:

```
import csv


mod1 = []
dev2 = []
d = {}
with open('/home/robi/Desktop/rob/device.csv', 'rb') as f:
    next(f, None)
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        mod1.append(row[0])
        dev2.append(row[1])

    a = zip(dev2, mod1)
    for it, key in a:
        print it + '.' + key
```

But I am getting results like this:

```
BAO.TEMP,HUM,RAN
BAR.TEMP,PRE
RAI.HUM
```

So `BAR` and `BAO` are not mapped correctly.

Comment: negative but why?. I would be happy to hear, so that in future I must be careful while asking questions

Comment: Your code throws the error `IndentationError: expected an indented block`, so that output **cannot** be from the code you presented here, as is. You should take more care when posting and you should leave out that you are grateful etc.: read and apply the last paragraph of [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to your posts and comments.

Comment: @Anthon I will follow these guidelines. I correct my indentation in code and i read this paragraph and i will follow as described.

Comment: Downvoting the answer without any reason is not good. at least some valid reason should be given. .

Comment: The reasons are displayed when you hover above the down arrow. It is on purpose that you don't have to comment or similar when you downvote. The chances that someone who downvoted your question actually sees your comment are minimal. I am the only one who gets notified of your messages, as I have commented. Nobody else gets notified, certainly not the downvoters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zip` works on `list` indices so it cannot recognize if there are more items in a specific item based on your criteria. You'll have to do some post-processing to build your end list, namely split the element from the first list by a comma and then combine each with the elements from the second list. Something like:

```
a = ['TEMP', 'TEMP,PRE', 'TEMP,HUM,RAN', 'HUM']
b = ['TEM', 'BAR', 'BAO', 'RAI']

c = ["%s.%s"%(e[1],i) for e in zip(a, b) for i in e[0].split(",")]
# ['TEM.TEMP', 'BAR.TEMP', 'BAR.PRE', 'BAO.TEMP', 'BAO.HUM', 'BAO.RAN', 'RAI.HUM']
```

Comment: thanks zwer for the help. your piece of code works fine , but JRG one looks simple to me and it also works. I cannot accept two answer, otherwise I would accept your one also. .but thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @robbin - except that his answer is not correct, at least as long as your question is `I want to map every item of b to a` - his code will give you a list of combinations of `a` and `b` which includes things like `BAR.RAN` and that's not in your desired output list. If you wanted all combinations of items in `a` and `b` you should update your question to reflect that.

Comment: yes I want to map every item of b to a. .wait i will check again. sorry my mistake. .

Comment: you are correct. its my mistake . his code gave me combinations. .I will make an apology to him and will accept your answer cox your were the second i guess to answer and your solution works fine.

Comment: `'.'.join((e[1],i))`is more readable to me than `"%s.%s"%(e[1],i)`

Comment: In Python 3.6+ you can also use the new f-strings: `[f'{e[1]}.{i}' for e in zip(a, b) for i in e[0].split(',')]`

Comment: When it comes to string formatting, I prefer `str.format()` and I rarely ever use the old-style string formatting. However, this is a way too simple of a concatenation to take the performance hit for [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) compliance. If we're adding alternatives, plain old string concatenation can work in this case too: `e[1] + "." + i`. It might even be the fastest of them all (but not in all Python versions/interpreters).

Comment: Our main concern is readability, but f-strings are probably the [fastest solution as well](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/) ("Performance considerations" at the bottom of the post).

Answer (score 2):

Try this at the end:

```
a = zip(dev2, mod1)
for it, key in a:
    words = key.split(',')
    for word in words:
        print it + '.' + word
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over items in `b` as it doesn't have multiple keys in single key and then iterate over items in `a` and check if it contains delimiter `,` and split over it.

I have additionally added code to have unique combinations using `set`, if you want.

```
def getCombinations(a, b):
    combinations = []
    for bitem in b:
        for aitem in a:
            if ("," in aitem):
                for aitemInner in aitem.split(","):
                    combinations.append(bitem + "." + aitemInner)
            else:
                combinations.append(bitem + "." + aitem)
    ## Optional : if you want unique combinations of B and A
    unique = set(combinations)
    return unique

a = ['TEMP', 'TEMP,PRE', 'TEMP,HUM,RAN', 'HUM']
b = ['TEM', 'BAR', 'BAO', 'RAI']
combinations = getCombinations(a, b)
print("Keys in a          : " + str(len(a)))
print("Keys in b          : " + str(len(b)))
print("Total Combinations : " + str(len(combinations)))
print(combinations)
```

Sample Run

```
Keys in a          : 4
Keys in b          : 4
Total Combinations : 16
{'TEM.HUM', 'RAI.HUM', 'BAR.PRE', 'BAO.HUM', 'TEM.PRE', 'RAI.RAN', 'RAI.TEMP', 'BAR.HUM', 'RAI.PRE', 'BAO.PRE', 'BAR.RAN', 'BAO.RAN', 'TEM.TEMP', 'TEM.RAN', 'BAO.TEMP', 'BAR.TEMP'}
```

`EDIT` : Updating the solution with the requirement that it doesn't need all combinations but it needs mapping of elements in b with a.

Here also, I am using `set` if you need unique mappings else you can return combinations from the `get1To1Mapping()` method.

`NOTE`: I am getting the minimum size of both the list and only giving mapping for no. of elements as per minimum list to avoid exception.

```
def get1To1Mapping(a, b):
    combinations = []
    ## some might argue to iterate over len(b) but i would go for minimum
    ## of both the list to avoid exception
    for index in range(min(len(a), len(b))):
        if ("," in a[index]):
            for aitem in a[index].split(","):
                combinations.append(b[index] + "." + aitem)
        else:
            combinations.append(b[index] + "." + a[index])
    ## optional : if you want just unique mappings
    unique = set(combinations)
    return unique

a = ['TEMP', 'TEMP,PRE', 'TEMP,HUM,RAN', 'HUM']
b = ['TEM', 'BAR', 'BAO', 'RAI']
combinations = get1To1Mapping(a, b)
print("Keys in a          : " + str(len(a)))
print("Keys in b          : " + str(len(b)))
print("Total Combinations : " + str(len(combinations)))
print(combinations)
```

Sample Run

```
Keys in a          : 4
Keys in b          : 4
Total Combinations : 7
{'BAR.PRE', 'RAI.HUM', 'TEM.TEMP', 'BAO.TEMP', 'BAO.HUM', 'BAO.RAN', 'BAR.TEMP'}
```

Comment: np, glad to help

Comment: No need to check before you split.

Comment: @JRG accept my apology, i didn't check properly. your code has one problem that it gave me combination. but i am trying just to map every element in b to a. .I will accept zwer answer. i am very sorry and its my mistake. I hope you will understand

Comment: no worries on accepting answer, I would like to correct my solution so it's workable for future references. Can you explain what you mean by mapping element in b to a, do you have expected output?

Comment: I have updated my solution with the solution you need just for future reference.

Comment: Dear down voter, why would you down vote when the solution(`get1To1Mapping`) gives OP's expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're lookin for?

```
 >>> [[(b[i], x) for x in a[i].split(',')] for i in range(len(a))]
 [[('TEM', 'TEMP')],
 [('BAR', 'TEMP'), ('BAR', 'PRE')],
 [('BAO', 'TEMP'), ('BAO', 'HUM'), ('BAO', 'RAN')],
 [('RAI', 'HUM')]]
```

Even though my answer wasn't good enough for you, here's a solution that would put it into strings like you seemed to want.

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [['.'.join((b[i], x)) for x in a[i].split(',')] for i in range(len(a))])
['TEM.TEMP',
 'BAR.TEMP',
 'BAR.PRE',
 'BAO.TEMP',
 'BAO.HUM',
 'BAO.RAN',
 'RAI.HUM']
```

Sadly, no one will ever see this, but at least *I* will know how awesome I am... /s

Answer (score 1):

Using `list comprehension` and `join` (*assuming a and b has same length*)

```
a = ['TEMP', 'TEMP,PRE', 'TEMP,HUM,RAN', 'HUM']
b = ['TEM', 'BAR', 'BAO', 'RAI']
length = len(a)

result = ['.'.join((b[index],sub_item) ) 
              for index in range(length) for sub_item in a[index].split(',')]
```

(*This seems to take little less time than using zip*)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are ignoring that you're reading a csv file. You can arrange the data in a more appropriate structure as soon as you read the file. Zipping such lists as yours together is an indicator that the data could be structured in a better way - a dictionary.

You can avoid the creation of the two lists and instead add the elements to a dictionary immediately (use a `collections.OrderedDict` if the elements have to be ordered):

```
dictio = {}

with open('csv_file.csv') as f:
    next(f, None)
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for mod1, dev2 in reader:
        dictio[dev2] = mod1.split(',')

for key, value in dictio.items():
    for word in value:
        print('{}.{}'.format(key, word))
```

Comment: I'm still not sure why you want to print these strings. Some more background info would be nice.

Comment: thanks for the help, actually I will write some code to perform some task and for that purpose i need to combine these two lists efficiently and store them so that I can perform some operations on it.

Comment: What kind of operations?

Comment: Somebody is downvoting the answers without reason. But at least that reminds me that I'm still interested in hearing what you're trying to do with your code. Maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: I have multiple csv files. and at the end I had to prepare yaml configuration file. .for this purpose first i had to perform some operations on certain columns of csv files to obtain them in First normal form (1NF). after that i will automate this task by deriving some logic. ....so certain columns contains more values separated by comma, therefore i had to transform them into 1NF form, that why i ask for mapping here in my question. .

Comment: I'm not sure if I can help you, but I suggest to create a correct and complete (executable) example and then post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get tips about optimizing the readability, code structure or performance.

Comment: I will make complete example and will post on the required site for help.